# datepicker not enabling date after 9th of month

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to create some specific days available for user, for that i have specified some date in range. Everything looks OK, Except, datepicker not selecting date beyond 9th of month.

I could not find error, if some one can help, that will be a great help.

**JsFiddle URL here :- http://jsfiddle.net/8AXaw/1/**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var availableDates = "2014-07-04, 2014-07-05, 2014-07-06, 2014-07-07, 2014-07-08, 2014-07-09, 2014-07-10, 2014-07-11, 2014-07-12, 2014-07-13, 2014-07-14, 2014-07-15, 2014-07-16, 2014-07-17, 2014-07-18, 2014-07-19, 2014-07-20, 2014-07-21, 2014-07-22, 2014-07-23, 2014-07-24, 2014-07-25, 2014-07-26, 2014-07-27, 2014-07-28, 2014-07-29, 2014-07-30, 2014-07-31, 2014-08-01, 2014-08-02, 2014-08-03, 2014-08-04, 2014-08-05";
    var availableDate = availableDates.split(', ');
    function available(date) {
       dmy = date.getFullYear() + '-0' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-0' +date.getDate();
       if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, availableDate) != -1) {
          return [true, '','Available'];
       } else {
         return [false,'','unAvailable'];
       }
    }
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });
</script>
```

**JsFiddle URL here :- http://jsfiddle.net/8AXaw/1/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the way you're constructing the date

```
var dmy = date.getFullYear() + '-0' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-0' +date.getDate();
```

Notice the zero, you're ending up with dates like

```
2014-07-08
2014-07-09
2014-07-010
2014-07-011
2014-07-012
```

And it's obvious why it only works up to `09`, as `010` is not valid, and you're doing the same with the months.

You can add a function that pads the numbers when neccessary instead

```
function available(date) {
    var dmy = date.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(date.getDate());
    if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, availableDate) != -1) {
        return [true, '', 'Available'];
    } else {
        return [false, '', 'unAvailable'];
    }
}

function pad(n) {
    return n < 10 ? ('0' + n) : n;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8AXaw/2/)